# Color pandas time series plot by column

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a simple Pandas dataframe for which I want to create a scatter plot and color each dot by the column `cat`. How can I do this? My x-axis is a `datetime64` dtype, so I cannot use Pandas' `scatter` function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 2.5, 1.2, 3.7],
    'b': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06'],
    'cat': ['cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat3']
})
df['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df['b'])
# This plots but doesn't color by 'cat'
df.plot(x='b', y='a', style='o')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='b', y='a', hue='cat')
```

Result:

[image: Scatterplot]